# Keep running into asset precompile error in my css...not sure why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, precompile

I keep getting errors like so when precompiling assets:

```
Invalid CSS after "...margin-left:1px": expected "{", was ";line-height:16..."
```

so I found an error in the css, which was it said "1margin-left:1px"...so i fixed that. now i'm running into another css error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...ced2>li{margin:": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "!inherit}.item-..."
```

but i don't see anything wrong with this code...here it is in full (I think this is it):

```
.item-list.spaced>li,.item-list.spaced2>li{margin:!inherit}.item-list>li.item-orange{border-left-color:#eccb71}
```

i'm not sure what the issue is here. anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!inherit` is invalid value. Probably you wanted to write `inherit !important`.

Comment: I purchased a theme from someone else so this is what came with it...didn't know that was invalid. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
item-list.spaced>li, .item-list.spaced2>li {
    margin: inherit;
}
.item-list>li.item-orange {
    border-left-color: #eccb71;
}
```